# How to use react native webview onNavigationStateChange for SPA built on react?

Tags: react-native, webview, react-native-webview

When working with react native web view I'm not able to change onNavigationStateChange as SPA load only once. Since state is not changing I'm not able to close the application when going back from different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/)?

If you use react router, It  will push current page URL to history API. So, onNavigationStateChange will be triggered.

I have a PWA with react router, and I can listen navigationchanges with "onNavigationStateChange".

Answer (score 0):

with spa and react-router dom you can  use `<a>` tag instead of `<Link>` from react-router-dom that is how I solve this issue on react native webview